# Inspect signature of a python function without the __code__ attribute (e.g. PyTorch)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I am trying to determine the signature of a PyTorch function at runtime (e.g. torch.empty or torch.zeros). But something like `inspect.signature(torch.empty)` doesn't work here:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import torch
>>> def add(a,b):
...     return a+b
... 
>>> inspect.signature(add)
<Signature (a, b)>
>>> inspect.signature(torch.empty)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anaconda/envs/gc/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 3105, in signature
    return Signature.from_callable(obj, follow_wrapped=follow_wrapped)
  File "/home/anaconda/envs/gc/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 2854, in from_callable
    return _signature_from_callable(obj, sigcls=cls,
  File "/home/anaconda/envs/gc/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 2308, in _signature_from_callable
    return _signature_from_builtin(sigcls, obj,
  File "/home/anaconda/envs/gc/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 2119, in _signature_from_builtin
    raise ValueError("no signature found for builtin {!r}".format(func))
ValueError: no signature found for builtin <built-in method empty of type object at 0x7f382e1321c0>
```

I am guessing the underlying reason to be the absence of the `__code__` attribute

```py
>>> add.__code__
<code object add at 0x7f382f3a9710, file "<stdin>", line 1>
>>> torch.empty.__code__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'
```

Is there any way to inspect the signatures of python functions in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

May be not best option, but workaround, - parse `torch.empty.__doc__`

```
print(torch.empty.__doc__)
```

---

```
    empty(*size, *, out=None, dtype=None, layout=torch.strided, device=None, requires_grad=False, pin_memory=False, memory_format=torch.contiguous_format) -> Tensor

Returns a tensor filled with uninitialized data. The shape of the tensor is
defined by the variable argument :attr:`size`.

Args:
...
```

Comment: That is not really consistent:
```python
>>> print(torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d.__doc__)
Applies a 2D max pooling over an input signal composed of several input
    planes.

    See :class:`~torch.nn.MaxPool2d` for details.
    
>>> 
```